# (q/kdb+) Delete column from tables saved in disk

Tags: kdb

I have the following table saved in the disk

```
`:t/ upsert ([] v1:10 20 30; v2:1.1 2.2 3.3; v3:1 2 3)
```

how can I delete column `v3` for instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work

`` `:t/ set delete v3 from t ``

Answer (score 4):

dbmaint.q is another option: https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/utils/dbmaint.q

This includes the function delete1col for this purpose. This can be used as so:

```
delete1col[tabledir;col]
```

in your case this would be:

```
delete1col[`:t/;`v3]
```

This script also includes a whole host of other functionality you may find useful in the future.

Comment: Note that the `delete1col` function deals with both removing the column (file) in question and also modifies the `.d` file appropriately.

Comment: I often think it's better to not delete the file, only remove the entry from the `.d` file, this allows the column to easily be added back in again in future. To achieve this, you can simply set `.os.del:{}` and then use `delete1col`

Comment: Interesting thing about this option is that it also deletes the file from the drive

Answer (score 2):

This line should achieve what you are looking to do:

```
`:/t/.d set `v1`v2
```

Additionally, you should delete your v3 file.

Hope that helps!